# Django-rest-framework working with 3 content-types how to manage renderers and serializers

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an api with `django-rest-framework` (last version) and I need different responses depending on the `content-type` asked.

Right now, I expect `application/vnd.api+json` or `text/html` (for browsable api). But I need to add another response for `application/vnd.oasis.stix+json; version=2.0`.

I tried to add a new custom renderer but it only allows me to specify "application/json". I have created this, but it takes all `json`content.

```
class StixRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/vnd.oasis.stix+json'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return super(StixRenderer, self).render(data, media_type, renderer_context)
```

I know that I can send differents serializers, but I don't know how to discriminate different content-types.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Do you have any code that you are stuck at?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with that piece of code